# How to convert a Persian date into a Gregorian date in xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I convert Persian date to Gregorian date in Xcode?

Please note that I want to convert my Persian Date  and get the Gregorian Date result in ULAlert view not in NSLog plz show me how

Comment: Please check out the Docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendars.html

Answer (score 11):

Is this what you want?

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df.calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSPersianCalendar];
df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
df.dateFormat = @"yyyy/MM/dd";
NSString *stringDate = @"1391/04/07";

NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:stringDate];

NSLog(@"Date %@", date);

df.calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar]; // or this one if ur current calendar is not GregorianCalendar [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar]
NSString *stringDateConverted = [df stringFromDate:date];
[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:stringDateConverted delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
```

Comment: plz show me how should I show that in alert view mode not in NSLog