# How to convert a Persian date into a Gregorian in swift

Tags: ios, swift, date

I want to convert data between "Persian date and Gregorian" in swift. I was looking into algorithm to help me convert between them, but I did not really understand how to implement them.

If their is an existing way to do the job in Swift please point me to it.

Providing and example will be also appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168261/how-to-convert-a-persian-date-into-a-gregorian-date-in-xcode

Comment: What stops you from running a seach on your own?

Comment: A date is a date. It isn't a Persian date or a Gregorian date. It's only when you display a date, or need to do calculations on it, that a calendar comes into play. Are you talking about converting dates (Date/NSDate objects) or date **strings**?

Comment: Hi  Duncan C. I want to converting dates from a Gregorian date to Persian date. like what this website [link](http://www.viewiran.com/calendar-converter.php) does, but in swift.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Update for Swift 3:**

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let date = Date()
print("Converted date to Grogrian = \(formatter.string(from: date))")
        
formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .persian)
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
print("Converted date to Hijri = \(formatter.string(from: date))")
```

Here are alternatives:

- era: G (AD), GGGG (Anno Domini)
- year: y (2018), yy (18), yyyy (2018)
- month: M, MM, MMM, MMMM, MMMMM
- day of month: d, dd
- day name of week: E, EEEE, EEEEE, EEEEEE

Comment: If you use `Date()` instead of `NSDate()`, you don't need the cast `as Date`. And I don't get why you set the date format twice with the same values.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 5: Format is little change for year

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/YYYY"
formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let date = Date()
let dateInGrogrian = formatter.string(from: date)

print(dateInGrogrian)

formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .persian)
formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/YYYY"
print("Converted date to Hijri = \(formatter.string(from: date))")
```

Answer (score 2):

I run into issue because I am running swift 2 NOT 3.(I am updatingXcode now)

here is the fix for the code above for people to see the changes from Swift 2 to Swift 3

```
import UIKit

let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyy/MM/dd"
formatter.calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
let date = NSDate()
let dateInGrogrian = formatter.stringFromDate(date)

print("Date in Grogrian = \(dateInGrogrian)")

formatter.calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierPersian)
formatter.dateFormat = "yyy/MM//dd"
print("Converted date to Jalali = \(formatter.stringFromDate(date))")
```