# how can I change Hijri(Islamic Calendar) string to Gregorian date in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, date

I am trying to convert an islamic calendar from string to gregorian and I searched the website and could not figure it out.

What I want to do is as follow:
I have an islamic date in a string as follow: "1439/02/1 22:30"

I want to change this date to the equivalent Gregorian date. How can I pass this to the Gregorian date formatter and construct the date.

all codes I came across were showing how to construct Gregorian date from the function date() not from other calendars.

Please note that I am not concerned about todays date at all. I am calculating the date from the past and I want the past Gregorian date.

(the closest solution i found) in the following link does not convert old dates. It construct the dates from todays date:
[How to convert a Persian date into a Gregorian in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41026346/how-to-convert-a-persian-date-into-a-gregorian-in-swift)
Moreover, the solution converts Gregorian to Persian not the vice versa (which I want).

It seams like swift is using Gregorian as the ِanchor

I very much appreciate your support.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a Persian date into a Gregorian in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41026346/how-to-convert-a-persian-date-into-a-gregorian-in-swift)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To parse the Islamic date string, you need a `DateFormatter` whose `calendar` property is set to the Islamic calendar.

To produce the Gregorian date string, you'll need a `DateFormatter` whose `calendar` is set to the Gregorian calendar. You can use the same `DateFormatter` and change the calendar, or you can use two separate `DateFormatter`s.

Example:

```
import Foundation

let islamicDateString = "1439/02/1 22:30"

let islamicFormatter = DateFormatter()
islamicFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"
// Note that there are actually four different Islamic calendars available on Apple platforms:
// .islamic, .islamicCivil, .islamicTabular, and .islamicUmmAlQura
// I don't know what the differences are.
islamicFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .islamic)

let gregorianFormatter = DateFormatter()
gregorianFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
gregorianFormatter.dateStyle = .short
gregorianFormatter.timeStyle = .short

if let date = islamicFormatter.date(from: islamicDateString) {
    let gregorianString = gregorianFormatter.string(from: date)
    print(gregorianString)
} else {
    print("I couldn't parse \(islamicDateString)")
}
```

Output:

```
10/20/17, 10:30 PM
```

Note that the output here depends on my time zone. You can also set each formatter's `timeZone` property if you don't want to use the user's time zone.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Rob